# Mosquitto - No data in $SYS topics

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

My setup has mosquitto 1.4.12 using TLS and user/pass authentication, it is working without issues under Ubuntu 14.04 for quite some time.

Problem is that no data is being published to any `$SYS` broker status topics. I have reviewed the configuration and `sys_interval` is set to 10. Is anything else needed to have this working?

I've tried many clients (mosquitto_sub, paho-mqtt, mqtt.fx), so it looks like a wrong mosquitto config, not a client issue.

mosquitto.conf looks like this:

```
sys_interval 10

max_queued_messages 10000
max_inflight_messages 100
max_connections -1

connection_messages true
log_dest stderr
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type all
log_timestamp true

password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/jp.pw
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/acl.conf

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistent_client_expiration 1m
autosave_interval 600
retained_persistence true

listener 8883
tls_version tlsv1.2

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/cert.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/cert.key
require_certificate false
allow_anonymous false
```

acl.conf has this, may be unnecessary:

```
user test
topic #
```

Comment: What exactly are you subscribing  to? the `$SYS` topics will not show up in a `#` subscription. You have to subscribe to `$SYS/#` to see all the data

Comment: yes @hardillb , I am subscribing to specific topics like `$SYS/broker/clients/active` or `$SYS/broker/uptime`

Comment: In that case edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf and any ACL you have set up so we can see what you've got setup

Comment: just done it, @hardillb. thanks.

Comment: Add a extra topic line that ends in `$SYS/#` just in case the came matching for topics is used for checking ACLs

Comment: Yes, you got it, that was the problem! Please post as an answer so I can mark as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The topic filter in the ACL applies the same rules as normal wildcard handling so just allowing access to `#` will not cover the `$SYS/#' topics.

You need to add a extra `topic` line to the ACL to include the `$SYS` topics:

```
user test
topic #
topic $SYS/#
```